# How to find the path for the most negatively-weighted cycle which goes through a specific source node?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, graph-algorithm, cycle, bellman-ford

I am trying to find the path for the most negative cycle in a graph G which starts and ends at a specified source node S.

I have studied an application/ extension of the Bellman-Ford algorithm (henceforth referred to as the "Huang algorithm") found [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.86.1981&rep=rep1&type=pdf) which describes how to find a negative cycle reachable from a specified node. However, this does not ensure that the "full cycle" going from S -> cycle -> S is negative.

Here is my current research into this topic:

On the n<sup>th</sup> iteration of the Bellman Ford algorithm, if an edge can be relaxed, then the graph contains a negative cycle. Using the Huang algorithm I can retrace the path of the negative cycle through the predecessor dictionary until a vertex repeats. When a vertex repeats, I cease iterating over the predecessor and now have my path for the negative cycle. However, the source vertex is often not in this path. I believe it is also sometimes not the most negatively-weighted path.

I would like to find the most negative cycle of which S is a part. (This can include a cycle with a subcycle detected by the Huang algorithm)

Comment: What exactly is the "most negatively weighted cycle"?

Comment: sorry, i realize this is not official jargon. I meant to say the cycle with the least weight where edges are not repeated.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your definitions, what you ask may be NP-complete. If you take a graph with no weights and give each edge weight -1 then the most negative cycle on any node you care to choose will have the most negative possible value if that cycle is a Hamiltonian path, so you have a means of finding if Hamiltonian paths exist, which solves an NP-complete problem. (This assumes that cycles cannot use the same vertex more than once, but if you use a definition where you can repeat vertices then you may have allowed paths of infinite length which go round and round forever).